# Need some Help in unity personal edition License matter

Tags: unity, legal

I am an independent developer, and I just started to look into Unity. I downloaded Unity Personal, and started setting it up. After sign up, a license page opened, in which I intended to selected a license for Unity Personal edition.

However, there are three options to choose from, and I don't know which one I should choose. Will I be able to make commercial games if I choose the 3rd option? I don't use Unity in a professional capacity.

Here are all the three options:-

1. The company/organisation I represent earned more than $100,000 in gross revenue in the previous fiscal year.
2. The company/organisation I represent earned less than $100,000 in gross revenue in the previous fiscal year.
3. I don't use unity in professional capacity.

Comment: Yes, you can make commercial games with it.

Comment: @Gnemlock He can totally answer questions via comments :)

Comment: -1 You're asking us to read the license for you.

Comment: I have edited the question please shed some light please and THNX IN ADVANCE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to obtain a license to use real car brands in a game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32469/do-i-need-to-obtain-a-license-to-use-real-car-brands-in-a-game)

Comment: @Almo I don't want to sound rude but if u don't want to answer then just don't say that it is a possible duplicate. By the way the question is different ok and i am thankful to all other people who answered my question and helped me atleast they all helped by sharing their knowledge unlike u who just saying that it is possible duplicate, shame on you, and one more thing first atleast try to read the question first.

Comment: It's still off topic. Shame on you for not reading the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>The below answer reflects the current licensing restrictions as of 16/9/2016. It is important to remember that Unity Technologies has the right to change this *at any time*. They also reserve the right to change these conditions under *pre-existing* licenses. It is therefore important that you *cross-check* this answer with the official Unity page, and perhaps even a legal representative, when using this answer as the basis to determine the viability of a particular Unity license for commercial release.</sup>

---

> If your company currently makes more than $100k in annual gross revenues or has raised funds in excess of $100k, you are not permitted to use Unity Personal as defined in our [EULA Agreement](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula). You may use [Unity Pro](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-pro) with an unlimited revenue capacity.
>
> <sup>**-- [Unity Personal download screen](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal)**</sup>

There is also a secondary restriction in the [EULA](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula) that states that *all* members of your team must be using the same license.

This means that you can use *Unity Personal* to release a commercial game, providing that

1. Your company<sup>1</sup> does not make over $100,000 USD<sup>2</sup> a year,
2. You are not able to raise over $100,000 USD<sup>2</sup> to fund your game and
3. If you work with other users, they also only use *Unity Personal*.

---

#### Revenue Restrictions

As per [the Unity EULA agreement](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula), you are restricted by how much your company makes. This is determined by annual gross revenues (how much you earn before deducations) and raised funds. This is great news, if you are an independent developer. Ultimately, you only have to pay for Unity *if* and *when* you can afford to.

Note that the direct quote from the [*Unity Personal* download screen](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal) reads that *"in excess of $100k, you are not permitted to use Unity Personal (...) You may use [Unity Pro](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-pro)"*. This is *slightly* misleading. While you *may* directly upgrade to *Unity Pro* for an unlimited revenue cap, the licensing page clearly supplies a middle option. We can presume that Unity Technologies are simply trying to "up-sell" in the above quote.

Licensed revenue restrictions are as follows:

- **Unity Personal**: Allows up to $100,000 USD<sup>2</sup> a year.
- **Unity Plus**: Allows up to $200,000 USD<sup>2</sup> a year.
- **Unity Pro**: Allows an unlimited revenue.

#### Team Restrictions

There are also restrictions when it comes to a team. It is simple enough, really. If you are making a game as a team, everybody needs to be using the same level of license. This makes fair sense. You can not simply buy one user license, so that one of your members has access to and can implement the advanced features.

It is worth double checking with your team, if working with other independent game developers. There are more than 3 Unity licenses, including an *Enterprise* license and an *Educational* license. It is important to know in certain contexts, other licenses *may* be made available to a particular user for free. For example, your fellow developer may report not having to pay for their Unity license. This *does not* mean they have the *Unity Personal* license. They might be using a *Unity Educational* license, provided through a college or university.

### Upgrading and Downgrading Licenses

As mentioned, you are allowed to upgrade licenses at your discretion. This means that you can simply start with the *Unity Personal* license, and upgrade to the *Unity Pro* license when your revenue reaches *Unity Personal* cap. You are also free to upgrade *early*, if you decide you wish to take advantage of the additional features.

It is important to note that during your subscription period, this move is one-way. During your "commitment period" (likely the subscription period, given that all licenses are now subscription based), you are not permitted to downgrade to a lower license.

> **Can I downgrade to a different tier?**
>
> No, you cannot downgrade to a lower tier during your commitment period. You can upgrade to a higher tier within your commitment period, however, you cannot reduce the number of seats if you upgrade.
>
> <sup>**--*Frequantly Asked Questions* posted on [the unity store front page](https://store.unity.com/front-page)**</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> There is no mention of how this may be interpreted for an independent developer, who may be considered a *sole trader*. In these cases, I can only advise you not to make assumptions, and to seek advice from a professional, such as a tax accountant or a lawyer.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> I make the presumption that figures are in US dollars, but this seems fairly obvious. The figures do not change with other localisation-based changes, and *Unity Technologies* is based in San Francisco, California.</sub>

Comment: "you only have to pay for Unity if and when your games start earning you some comfortable profit." - I think this may be misleading, by my reading (please correct me if I'm mistaken): 1. This threshold is based on revenue, not profit, so as long as the game has sold/raised $X in a year, I need to upgrade my license, even if my cut/balance after expenses was substantially smaller. 2. Since this includes "raised funds" if I get crowdfunding or seed funding in excess of $X in a year I need to upgrade my licence, even if the game hasn't been finished/released yet. Is that right?

Comment: @DMGregory - that is correct, yes.

Comment: Gross revenue is "[total revenue received *before* any deductions or allowances](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gross-income)" - are you thinking of "[net](http://www.investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/businesses-corporations/net-revenue-2616)" or "[sales](http://www.moneychimp.com/glossary/sales_revenue.htm)" revenue?

Comment: @DMGregory, I stand corrected. Its been a while since I did economics. It seems the website I used to double check the exact meaning was not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

*"Will I be able to make commercial games"* and *"I don't use Unity in a professional capacity"* is a contradiction. You find an overview of the differences between the different license plans on [store.unity.com](https://store.unity.com/).

When you are just checking it out and are not sure if you want to use it commercially, you can start with the gratis version ("Personal Edition"). Should you later decide that you want to release a game you made commercially and think you will make more than $100,000 (or just want to get rid of the "Made With Unity" splash screen) you can always get a subscription plan for one of the paid versions. A project started under the personal license can be continued after upgrading to a paid license.

Comment: I don't see how the two are a contradiction, at least, not in the context of Unity. *You do not have to have a professional license to release games commercially*.

Comment: @Gnemlock so in short i can make commercial games using unity personal edition with selecting the 3rd option right. i have added all the 3 option it was showing in my question please check it out now sir. N THNX IN ADVANCE :)